# SwiftUI: getting error when trying to pass in FetchedRequest data as EnvironmentObject to subView

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a small app and I am trying to use CoreData to persist items and if it's first launch, they will come from a JSON and get saved to CoreData for all future reloads.
If `foods`, which comes from fetching CoreData data, has a count of < 1, then that means it's a first time launch and I iterate through the decoded JSON data and save it to CoreData.

I am getting an error when trying to pass the `foods` into my `MainView` saying:

```
Instance method 'environmentObject' requires that 'FetchedResults<Food>' conform to 'ObservableObject'
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct myApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()

    @State var jsonData: [Food] = Bundle.main.decode("Foods.json")
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []
      ) var foods: FetchedResults<Food>
    
     init() {
        if foods.count < 1 {
            
            let newFood = Food(context: dataController.container.viewContext)
            
            for item in jsonData {
                newFood.id = Int16(item.id)
                newCountry.isEdible = item.isEdible
                newCountry.name = item.name
                newCountry.list_names = country.list_names as NSArray

                
                do {
                    try dataController.container.viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let error = error as NSError
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()     
               .environmentObject(foods)        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An `EnvironmentObject` needs to conform to `ObservableObject`. `FetchedResults` is NOT an `ObservableObject`

Comment: is there another way I can pass these down other than as an argument into the view?

Comment: You can use `NSFetchRequest` or `NSFetchRequestController` inside an `ObservableObject` but if you look at Apple's new project sample code for CoreData you can mimic the `preview` behavior in the `shared`. You might be over complicating something simple. I am not sure why you want to pass the `FetchedResults`

Comment: how else would I get the CoreData into other views though?  Making a FetchRequest in each view I need that data?

Comment: Either that or you create a class that holds the object and the use it in your app as either a StateObject or EnvironmentObject.